# Main thread can't load all the RecyclerView items. What is the best approach?

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a simple Android application (Kotlin) that loads a list of items with a RecyclerView. Each item has 9 buttons, each playing a sound. Since I have 72 items, that's 72*9 times I attach a sound to a button. If I only load 10 or less items, there's no problem. If I load all the 72, I start getting *E/MediaPlayerNative: Unable to create media player* because it's too much work for the main thread.

Here's what I'm doing on *onBindViewHolder*:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val context = holder.view.context
    holder.view.info_text.text = tracks[position].name

    val sounds: ArrayList<MediaPlayer> = ArrayList()
    for(i in 1..9 ) {
        sounds.add(MediaPlayer.create(context, context.resources.getIdentifier("c${tracks[position].number}_${i}", "raw", context.applicationInfo.packageName)))
    }

    holder.view.preview_grid.children.forEach {
        val row: TableRow = it as TableRow
        row.children.forEach {
            it.setOnClickListener {
                val number = it.tag.toString().toInt()
                sounds.get(number).start()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Doing this 72 times on the main thread isn't working, so what approach should I go for here?

Comment: Use pagination. First load 10 items or as per your design.

Comment: When you say isn't working, it crashes or it is just soft error in logs printed?

Comment: You should release resources in `onViewRecycled()`

Comment: @DMdeveloping After a few items, 90% of the sounds don't get added because `MediaPlayer.create` takes time and it keeps printing out erros regarding that.

Comment: Ok, than your solution is as Ali recommended: pagination!

Comment: Call MediaPlayer.create in setOnClickListener method. In the list sounds, you should store just ids.